# Spring injection depending on a certain property

Tags: java, spring

I have to implement services for different types of contracts. At first, we thought about creating a spring service that would redirect to a type specific service using if else structure.

There must be a better solution with spring.

Is there an easy way to dynamically inject a service per type using spring knowing that there would be an abstract service and one implementation per type.

Example:

```
@Inject ContractService contractService;
...   
Contract iContract = new InsuranceContract(...); 
Contract sContract = new SaleContract(...);
...
contractService.save(sContract);
contractService.save(iContract);
```

The ContractService would be abstract and spring would get the right service depending on the contract type.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is not suited for your domain logic, even though you can achieve it by overriding certain methods in your class which Spring would automatically call before assigning the appropriate bean,  but I wouldn't recommend it to you, just because plain java code is better suited for this type of tasks.

I would recommend you to go for the solution you originally suggested

> I have to implement services for different types of contracts. At first, we thought about creating a spring service that would redirect to a type specific service using if else structure.

If you think about it, in your underlying problem, you have to deal with a if/else if scenario, where you would rather see this, in XML or in Java? I think in general is better to see this in Java and leave Spring for what is best at.

Comment: Would a solution using naming convention and reflection be a better solution then?

Comment: IMHO I would go for the simplest solution... So, if you only have one interface and a few implementations, I would go for the explicit solution, that's it, create a Service Locator as you were saying... If you have a more complex scenario, with many, many interfaces and implementations, then I would consider the reflection solution.. You have to keep in mind that the more you use out of the standard java solutions ie Frameworks, reflection... The more difficult to read and maintain your code.